# How to return raster values based on polygon (shapefile) boundaries in QGIS?

Tags: raster, qgis, grass-gis

How to return raster values based on polygon (shapefile) boundaries in QGIS?

Is this an elementary question, because I am finding it hard.......
Ideally I would like a neat workflow as I am likely to repeat the task, even if it includes using GRASS.

I want to take a remote sensed raster ( Landsat ), and load it up with a shapefile containing irregular polygons and return the avg, max min of the raster values for each polygon.

Ideally I would also like to clip out the polygons as separate files for each polygon, perhaps that is another post, but probably it is a related process, which I haven't been able to tackle yet.

And is QGIS the right platform to be tackling this in? I have loaded up the RASTERCALC Plugin which does give better functionality than the default raster calculator, so have made a little progress there.

Any thoughts appreciated

Comment: Googling "zonal statistics" might turn up some leads.  For a wider variety of solutions try "zonal statistics -arcview -arcgis" :-).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Currently, I don't know of such a function for QGIS.

But in GRASS there is **v.rast.stats** (Calculates univariate statistics from a raster map based on vector polygons and uploads statistics to new attribute columns.) - [Documentation](http://grass.osgeo.org/gdp/html_grass64/v.rast.stats.html)

GRASS is scriptable, so if you have to repeat this task multiple times, writing a script might save you some time.

---

Update:

QGIS dev version now has a new Zonal stats plugin in Raster menu

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[agoodle](https://github.com/brentp/agoodle) could be worth a look

Comment: Read http://hackmap.blogspot.com/2010/05/numpy-gdal-agoodle.html for a short introduction